# How to programmatically set color in gimp (pythonfu)?

Tags: gimp, gimpfu, python-fu

Using Python, I was able to add a floating text layer using

```
text_layer = pdb.gimp_text_fontname(image, drawable, x, y, text, border, antialias, size, size_type, fontname)
```

However, the text appears in black. Specifically `pdb.gimp_text_layer_get_color(text_layer)` returns `RGB (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`

I want the font to be in a different color.

I tried

```
col = gimpcolor.RGB(44.7, 46.7, 58.0)
pdb.gimp_text_layer_set_color(text_layer, col)
```

Trying `pdb.gimp_text_layer_get_color(text_layer)` now returns `RGB (44.7, 46.7, 58.0, 1.0)` but the text in now in white.

How to make the text appear in my desired color or where does gimpcolor object's documentation exist?

Comment: [jsbueno's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25982891/19530650) answer, mentioning that color param can be passed a string. In this case, passing the '#rrggbb' worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is created with the current foreground color:

```
# Two ways to set the color (pick one)

# Color set with the gimp object
gimp.set_foreground(gimpcolor.RGB(0,0,255))

# Color set via PDB API
pdb.gimp_context_set_foreground(gimpcolor.RGB(0,0,255))

text_layer = pdb.gimp_text_fontname(image, None, 100, 100, 'Gimp', 0, True, 80,0, 'Bungee')
```

Also: careful with number types of the color channels. AFAIK for `gimpcolor.RGB(r,g,b)`:

- if the r/g/b argument is a float, it is understood as being in the `[0.0 .. 1.0]` range (and clamped if outside that range)
- if it is an integer, is is understood as being in the `[0 .. 255]` range

So for instance `gimpcolor.RGB(1.,1.,1.)` is white (`1. = 100%`), but `gimpcolor.RGB(1,1,1)` is nearly black (`1/255 = 0.4%`).